# I am trying to give better look to my dynamic pagination but its not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have dynamic pagination for products. My pagination work fine just I want to give a better look for my pagination.

view:

```
 <div  style='margin-top: 10px;' class="page-link" align="center">
   <?= $pagination; ?>
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
function category($rowno=0)
       {
        $rootCatId  =   $this->input->get('rootCatId');
        $subCatId   =   $this->input->get('subCatId');
        $rowno      =   $this->input->get('per_page');
        $data=array();
        if($rootCatId > 0 && $subCatId== 0){
            $rowperpage = 12;
            if($rowno != 0){
              $rowno = ($rowno-1) * $rowperpage;
            }
            $search_text = "";
            if($this->input->post('submit') != NULL ){
              $search_text = $this->input->post('search');
              $this->session->set_userdata(array("search"=>$search_text));
            }else{
              if($this->session->userdata('search_product') != NULL){
                $search_text = $this->session->userdata('search_product');
              }
            }
            $rowperpage = 12;
            if($rowno != 0){
              $rowno = ($rowno-1) * $rowperpage;
            }
            $allcount = $this->product->getrecordCount($search_text);
            $users_record = $this->product->fetchAllProductByMainCat($rootCatId,$rowno,$rowperpage,$search_text);
            $config['base_url']             = base_url().'category';
            $config['uri_segment']          = 3;
            $config['reuse_query_string']   = TRUE;
            $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
            $config['page_query_string']    = TRUE;
            $config['use_page_numbers']     = TRUE;
            $config['total_rows']           = $allcount;
            $config['per_page']             = $rowperpage;
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="page-link">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
            $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
            $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

            // Initialize
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $data['viewAll']    = $users_record;
            $data['row']        = $rowno;
            $data['search']     = $search_text;

         }elseif($rootCatId > 0 && $subCatId !==0 && $subCatId > 0){

                $rowperpage = 12;
                if($rowno != 0){
                  $rowno = ($rowno-1) * $rowperpage;
                }

                $search_text = "";
                if($this->input->post('submit') != NULL ){
                  $search_text = $this->input->post('search');
                  $this->session->set_userdata(array("search"=>$search_text));
                }else{
                  if($this->session->userdata('search_product') != NULL){
                    $search_text = $this->session->userdata('search_product');
                  }
                }
                $allcount = $this->product->getrecordCount($search_text);
                $users_record = $this->product->fetchProductByCat($rootCatId,$subCatId,$rowno,$rowperpage,$search_text);
                $config['base_url'] = base_url().'category';
                $config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;
                $config['enable_query_strings']=TRUE;
                $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
                $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
                $config['total_rows'] = $allcount;
                $config['per_page'] = $rowperpage;
                $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="page-link">';
                $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
                $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
                $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
                $this->pagination->initialize($config);
                $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
                $data['viewAll'] = $users_record;
                $data['row'] = $rowno;
                $data['search'] = $search_text;
          }
                $data['get_website_content'] = $this->pg_model->get_website_content();
                $data['BannerImage']         = $this->product->fetchBannerImage($rootCatId);
                $data['MainName']            = $this->product->NameByMainCat($rootCatId);
                $data['SubName']             = $this->product->NameBySubCat($subCatId);

                $data['product_list_commercial']    = $this->pg_model->product_list_commercial();
                $this->load->view('template/header',$data);
                $this->load->view('category');
                $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
```

I want to show pagination looks like the following image.

[image]

With `$config` I set the all neccessary configration for pagination. I do not know where I am wrong in my code

Comment: Some of these days now, it might be about time that you learn how to ask a question … _“I do not know where I am wrong in my code”_ - how should _we_ know? You did not show us what it currently looks like, you did not describe in _any way_ what is currently “wrong” about the result in your opinion …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing good but not added the html tags in the custom pagination. Just add some lines in between your current code.

```
function category($rowno=0)
       {
        $rootCatId  =   $this->input->get('rootCatId');
        $subCatId   =   $this->input->get('subCatId');
        $rowno      =   $this->input->get('per_page');
        $data=array();
        if($rootCatId > 0 && $subCatId== 0){
            $rowperpage = 12;
            if($rowno != 0){
              $rowno = ($rowno-1) * $rowperpage;
            }
            $search_text = "";
            if($this->input->post('submit') != NULL ){
              $search_text = $this->input->post('search');
              $this->session->set_userdata(array("search"=>$search_text));
            }else{
              if($this->session->userdata('search_product') != NULL){
                $search_text = $this->session->userdata('search_product');
              }
            }
            $rowperpage = 12;
            if($rowno != 0){
              $rowno = ($rowno-1) * $rowperpage;
            }
            $allcount = $this->product->getrecordCount($search_text);
            $users_record = $this->product->fetchAllProductByMainCat($rootCatId,$rowno,$rowperpage,$search_text);
            $config['base_url']             = base_url().'category';
            $config['uri_segment']          = 3;
            $config['reuse_query_string']   = TRUE;
            $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
            $config['page_query_string']    = TRUE;
            $config['use_page_numbers']     = TRUE;
            $config['total_rows']           = $allcount;
            $config['per_page']             = $rowperpage;
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="page-link">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
            $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
            $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

            //This segment is used for the design (looks) start here
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
            $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
            $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
            $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
            $config['next_tagl_close'] = '</a></li>';
            $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
            $config['prev_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item disabled">';
            $config['first_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
            $config['last_tagl_close'] = '</a></li>';
            $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'page-link');
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
             //This segment is used for the design (looks) end here
            // Initialize
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $data['viewAll']    = $users_record;
            $data['row']        = $rowno;
            $data['search']     = $search_text;

         }elseif($rootCatId > 0 && $subCatId !==0 && $subCatId > 0){

                $rowperpage = 12;
                if($rowno != 0){
                  $rowno = ($rowno-1) * $rowperpage;
                }

                $search_text = "";
                if($this->input->post('submit') != NULL ){
                  $search_text = $this->input->post('search');
                  $this->session->set_userdata(array("search"=>$search_text));
                }else{
                  if($this->session->userdata('search_product') != NULL){
                    $search_text = $this->session->userdata('search_product');
                  }
                }
                $allcount = $this->product->getrecordCount($search_text);
                $users_record = $this->product->fetchProductByCat($rootCatId,$subCatId,$rowno,$rowperpage,$search_text);
                $config['base_url'] = base_url().'category';
                $config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;
                $config['enable_query_strings']=TRUE;
                $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
                $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
                $config['total_rows'] = $allcount;
                $config['per_page'] = $rowperpage;
                $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="page-link">';
                $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
                $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
                $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

                //This segment is used for the design (looks) start here
                $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
                $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
                $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
                $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
                $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">';
                $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
                $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
                $config['next_tagl_close'] = '</a></li>';
                $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
                $config['prev_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
                $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item disabled">';
                $config['first_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
                $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
                $config['last_tagl_close'] = '</a></li>';
                $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'page-link');
                $this->pagination->initialize($config);
                 //This segment is used for the design (looks) end here

                $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
                $data['viewAll'] = $users_record;
                $data['row'] = $rowno;
                $data['search'] = $search_text;
          }
                $data['get_website_content'] = $this->pg_model->get_website_content();
                $data['BannerImage']         = $this->product->fetchBannerImage($rootCatId);
                $data['MainName']            = $this->product->NameByMainCat($rootCatId);
                $data['SubName']             = $this->product->NameBySubCat($subCatId);

                $data['product_list_commercial']    = $this->pg_model->product_list_commercial();
                $this->load->view('template/header',$data);
                $this->load->view('category');
                $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
```

After this you can add your custom css based on the added class attribute include on html.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap then you can use the following code along with your other config values,

```
/* Pagination buttion style start  */
    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';        
    $config['prev_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';        
    $config['next_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    /* Pagination buttion style end */
```